# Scala iterator: "one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it" - why?

Tags: scala, iterator

Scala documentation on Iterator[T] [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator) says the following:

> It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise, one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it. The two most important exceptions are also the sole abstract methods: `next` and `hasNext`.

They also give a specific example of safe and unsafe use:

```
def f[A](it: Iterator[A]) = {
  if (it.hasNext) {            // Safe to reuse "it" after "hasNext"
    it.next                    // Safe to reuse "it" after "next"
    val remainder = it.drop(2) // it is *not* safe to use "it" again after this line!
    remainder.take(2)          // it is *not* safe to use "remainder" after this line!
  } else it
}
```

Unfortunately I don't follow the idea of unsafety here.  Could someone shed some light for me here?

Comment: "Reuse: After calling drop/take method, one should discard the iterator it was called on, and use only the iterator that was returned. Using the old iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in changes to the new iterator as well."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val remainder = it.drop(2)` may be implemented like that: it creates a new wrapper iterator that keeps a reference to the original `it` operator and advance it twice, so that the next time you call `remainder.next` you get the 3rd element. But if you then call `it.next` in between, `remainder.next` will return the 4th element...

So you have to references `remainder` and `it` that may need to call `next` and do the same side effect, which is not supported by the implementation.

Comment: Thanks.  So in a sense calling methods like drop transfers the ownership of the iterator to the returned one.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a concrete example:

```
def eleventh[A](xs: Iterator[A]) = {
  xs.take(10).toList
  xs.next
}
```

We can try it out:

```
scala> eleventh((1 to 100).toList.toIterator)
res0: Int = 11

scala> eleventh((1 to 100).toStream.toIterator)
res1: Int = 11

scala> eleventh(Stream.from(1).toIterator)
res2: Int = 11
```

Looks fine. But then:

```
scala> eleventh((1 to 100).toIterator)
res3: Int = 1
```

Now `(1 to 100).toIterator` has the same type as `(1 to 100).toList.toIterator`, but the two behave very differently here—we're seeing implementation details leak out of the API. That's a very bad thing, and is the direct result of mixing purely functional combinators like `take` with an inherently imperative and mutable concept like the iterator.